# How to limit xen dom0 RAM to a certain amount?

Tags: grub2, xen

How to limit xen dom0 RAM to a certain amount?

When there was grub1 and a grub.cfg, I knew how, just add to the kernel options there.

Now I have no clue. I have tried setting `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset dom0_mem=640M,max:640M"` in /etc/default/grub but no effect, dom0 still uses all RAM.

Answer (score 4):

The line you have to add in `/etc/default/grub` is:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_XEN_DEFAULT="dom0_mem=min:640M,max:640M"`

and:

```
update-grub
reboot
```

Comment: and also set (dom0-min-mem 640) in /etc/xen/xend-config.sxp